# new org-mode buffer with font-lock off

Tags: font-lock

I am making a new buffer, then disabling font-lock.  I use headings, I have noticed that they do not get coloured.  Is this how things work ?

Do buffers in modes with font-lock enabled always require font lock for doing the highlighting ?  Is one able to have mode-like highlighting just for display purposes, and then add my own properties to it.  But something that would only work for that specific buffer, so my rules would not spill over when loading org-mode files.

Comment: What happens when you turn `font-lock` back on?

Comment: `org-mode` uses `font-lock` to colorize the text.  `org-agenda-mode` uses `text-properties`, instead of `font-lock`, to colorize the `*Org Agenda*` buffer.

Comment: When I turn font-lock on, the colours resume.

Comment: Had turned `font-lock` on to use some colours when I insert in a buffer with `org-mode` enabled.  As you described, `font-lock` colourises headings, but had hoped that when `font-lock` is off, the text properties are retained, but the colours would not override the user ones.

Comment: Clearly this is "how things work", since you describe what happens. What's the question?

Comment: Do buffers in modes with font-lock enabled always require font lock for doing the highlighting?  Is one able to have mode-like highlighting just for display purposes, and then add my own properties to it.  But something that would only work for that specific buffer, so my rules would not spill over when loading `org-mode` files.

Comment: I changed the question in the text as well, you dummy !

Comment: Apologies: I did not notice it.

Comment: No apologies required, considering the grief I give on my emacs wonders. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways to highlight text. One way to have your own highlighting for a specific buffer is using `hi-lock-mode`. From its docstring:

> In buffers where Font Lock mode is enabled, patterns are
> highlighted using font lock.  In buffers where Font Lock mode is
> disabled, patterns are applied using overlays; in this case, the
> highlighting will not be updated as you type.

See [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74929/using-a-sub-expression-for-highlight-regexp) for an example of how to use it.