# Using a sub-expression for `highlight-regexp`

Tags: regular-expressions, highlighting, comment

I have made a face to highlight elisp comments starting with `;; [` using `hi-lock`.  My intention is to only colour the expression `[text]` using `SUBEXP`.

```
(highlight-regexp "^;; \\[.+\\].+$" 'face-aid "\\[.+\\]"))
```

Tho above does not do the highlight.  How does one construct `SUBEXP` exactly?

The documentation for `highlight-regexp` states that the function limits face setting to the corresponding `SUBEXP` of `REGEXP`.  But does not say how a `SUBEXP` would look like.  Using `"\\[.+\\]"` for `SUBEXP` is definitely incorrect.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: How to define `subexp` in `highlight-regexp`.

Comment: Then edit your question to ask that!

Comment: It's not clear what's unclear to you. Answering your question by just quoting the doc would **seem** to answer it. Assuming you've read the doc, that's apparently not the case, so just what your problem is isn't clear from the question. What part of the description of `SUBEXP` do you have trouble understanding?

Answer (score 3):

By SUBEXP a [match group](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html) is meant. Match groups are defined by `\\( ... \\)` and they are numbered 0 (for the whole match), 1 (for whatever is within the first `\\( ... \\)`, etc.

So the following would apply the face only to the match group 1:

```
(highlight-regexp "^;; \\(\\[.+\\]\\).+$" 'error 1)
```

Comment: You've got a typo: `\(( ... \\)` instead of `\\( ... \\)`. (I'd make an edit but given my rep on this stack, I can only suggest an edit of 6+ characters, but this is only a change of 2-4 characters.)