# Colouring different parts of a comment

Tags: colors, comment

I want to change the colour of substrings inside comments in a buffer. So that text enclosed by braces are coloured differently.

For the following bash comment, I want the text enclosed bf `{}` to be differently coloured.  For instance, the comment will be green but with `{this and that}` being blue.

```
## This is a comment that describes {this and that}.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a sub-expression for \`highlight-regexp\`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74929/using-a-sub-expression-for-highlight-regexp)

Answer (score 2):

This is more or less a duplicate of [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/74929/using-a-sub-expression-for-highlight-regexp) (where you probably forgot to accept the correct answer).

Anyway, you can achieve this using `hi-lock-mode` and evaluating the following expression

```lisp
(highlight-regexp "^## .*\\({.+}\\)\.*$" 'face-aid 1)
```